# pgfplots: Group ybar

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to group some bars in pgfplots. In the first figure the two left bars and the two right bars should be grouped. Of course I do **not** want to manipulate the data, as done in figure two. Also the labels should move with the bars.

*Figure 2 is only for illustration!*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=5
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=5
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1.3,1) (1.7,2) (3.3,3) (3.7,4)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Two colors is not enough for you? For example, you can use `\addplot` twice with different data set.

Comment: @Sigur Right now I don't know, if this is enough. I wanted to test it, but somehow `\addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2)}; \addplot coordinates {(3,3) (4,4)};` causes the bars to displayed at x-values: 0.8, 1.8, 3.2, 4.2

Comment: @Sigur Of course! This is done so that the bars of different sets aren't displayed over each other. Do you know how to deactivate this shift?

Comment: `bar shift=false` solves this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.